# Handling UITableView or NSArray exceptions?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, exception

I'm trying to understand exceptions a little more. I've installed in my AppDelegate an uncaught exception handler:

```
// in applicationDidFinishLaunching:
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleExceptions);
...
void HandleExceptions(NSException *exception) {
    // Save application data on crash
    [appDelegate saveData];
}
```

So I'm not entirely sure how this works. Say I access an array out of bounds, which throws an exception. Why does this method not get called? Or say there is an assertion exception thrown after inserting or removing rows from a table - how can I save data before the app crashes in those situations?

In general, when the system throws an exception, how can I have the chance to save data before the app crashes? Or does it not work like that? Is the uncaught exception handler only for exceptions that I throw that are not enwrapped in a @catch or @try?

Comment: It's just for uncaught exceptions.  If you catch them somewhere else, they are not uncaught.  Also, this question lacks sufficient information.  You need to provide a specific example of code that does not work as you expect.

Comment: @JodyHagins _it_ does not work as I expect..the whole thing.

Comment: If I access an array out of bounds without any `@try` or `@catch`, the method doesn't get called. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Let me add that blindly saving in an uncaught exception handler is not good practice.  You have no idea why you got there, and you could be corrupting your data store.  In general, you want to do as little as possible here that might mutate and data.

Comment: @JodyHagins really? Any idea where I could read more about this?

Comment: Not really.  Google uncaught exceptions, maybe.  At least in C++, there is the concept of exception safety, and lots of modern C++ code is written to behave appropriately in the presence of exceptions.  Even then, you would never try to save data in a terminate or exit handler, having no idea how you got there.  In Objective-C, it's much worse. You don't know how you got to the uncaught exception.  Maybe it happened while changing some data that the system could not handle, maybe as a result, some data cleanup that was supposed to happen didn't happen and now your view of the world is corrupt.

Comment: Exceptions in Objective C are just bad news.  If you want to try/catch/finally them and do some local stuff, then fine.  A general uncaught handler that changes persistent data?  I'd never want that in any of my code, and I've become quite permissive in my old age...  I do evil Objective-C stuff like method swizzling, and executing code in +load, and static constructor/destructor functions, and I've even used sscanf and setjmp/longjmp, not to mention an occasional goto.  Gasp!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps 'appDelegate' is nil when your method is called. I just added this to a viewController:

```
void HandleExceptions(NSException *exception) {
    // Save application data on crash
    NSLog(@"YIKES");
}
```

then did this:

```
NSArray *foo = @[ @1, @2, @3 ];
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleExceptions);
NSLog(@"%@", [foo objectAtIndex:3]);
```

and got this:

```
2012-09-06 13:51:17.474 Searcher[64798:f803] YIKES
2012-09-06 13:51:17.475 Searcher[64798:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x67f022 0x1749cd6 0x66b644 0x324d 0xbb8a1e 0xb17401 0xb17670 0xb17836 0xc9addd8 0xb1e72a 0x2fcd 0xaef386 0xaf0274 0xaff183 0xaffc38 0xaf3634 0x2260ef5 0x653195 0x5b7ff2 0x5b68da 0x5b5d84 0x5b5c9b 0xaefc65 0xaf1626 0x2dfc 0x2d95
```

Comment: That's weird..I did exactly what you did and put that code in my applicationDidFinishLuanching, but it doesn't get called

Comment: And I just put it in a view controller, but it still didn't get called. I'm doing exactly what you're doing. What can cause this?

Comment: Ok actually wait - after I hit the play button several times in the debugger the log statement finally came up. So I guess it does work :)

Comment: Add a log message as I did. Add my code above right after you set the handler, see if its called. Try creating a brand new test project (as I did) and do the test with it. If it works then there is some setting in your project that is causing the issue - I tried with 'Objective-C Exceptions' on and off, it worked in both cases.

Comment: So at this point, using that exact code as above, is there anyway to save the app from crashing? Or that's only if I use try/catch?

Comment: Try/catch is essentially used for saving a crash report or emailing someone. It leaks - its not like C++ that unwinds the stack freeing everything. Any allocated object between the location of the crash and your try block are leaked. This is why its not considered good practice to use try/catch as a design element. What you can do is pop an alert, tell the user that something has gone terribly wrong, please send the crash report to you, then die.

Comment: So if we can do all sorts of fancy things like present an alert, send an email, why can't we just continue program execution all together? Is it technically feasible but just not safe to do so, so it's been prohibited all together? Or is it just technically impossible?

Comment: You would need to figure out what you left dangling - the objects could be delegates or whatever. Its not a good idea but not impossible. The closer you can get a try/catch to the actual class that causes the exception the better. Most of us are very poor guessers of where the exceptions are going to occur.